# Java - Wav File - Null Byte?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have a weird question. Right now, I'm able to read wav files samples and after process them, saving it again into file. But for my project, I have to change some bytes with null value. I mean, if I put into some integer into wav file (for example: binary form of 25) that's mean sound card will give us electric signal which is powered of 25(I could have some misunderstanding about sound cards and wav files concepts).

But in my project I need to put `null` values into wav file. Like when sound card read binary form of 25, it will give signal but after that there will be to null byte and sound card won't give any electric signal since another value comes.

I know, I could not express my question properly. To make it more understandable;

Let's suppose there is file which is stored like that

```
data[] = {10,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,11,10};
```

I want to make it

```
data[]= {10,12,13,14,null,null,null,12,11,10}
```

and when sound card read this data, It will give us for example

```
10 voltage,12 voltage,13 voltage,14 voltage,no any signal,no any signal,no any signal,12 voltage, 11 voltage, 10 voltage}
```

Comment: Just use the value `0` instead of `null`.

Comment: *"I have a weird question."*  Most of the time, that should prompt a check of the basic facts.  Do you actually mean you want to write 'silence' to parts of the audio file?  Another way to put it is to 'mute' parts of the sound signal.  Note that writing pure '0' values in parts of sound files will generally cause a loud click at the start and end of the silenced section.  It is better to fade (very quickly) form normal volume to 0 at the start, then back again at the end.

Comment: We might be able to help you more if you added more detail and mentioned what you want to do in broader terms. E.g. "I have 10 seconds of 8KHz/8bit signed PCM audio in a Java byte array and I want to insert 1 second of silence after the fifth second"...

Comment: I have 48khz, 8 bit mono, 50 second wav file, I extracted it and I get byte array.And yes, I want to insert silence between 30 and 40 second.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that a WAV file has a specific way of representing "no signal" in the middle of a waveform.  (A cursory reading of [this description](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) seems to confirm this.)

I think your best bet is to simply use zeros where you have no signal.  (Obviously, the zeros will needed to be encoded using your chosen codec.)

---

By the way, even if the WAV file did have a way of representing "no signal", it would not involve putting `null` values into a Java byte array.  A Java byte array cannot contain `null`s ... ever.  The Java Language Specification forbids it.

Comment: Note that constant values of .. any value in range will achieve the same effect.  Going directly from '14' in one sample to '0,0,0,..' in the next samples will typically cause a loud 'clicking' type sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `null` into a file when you're dealing with bytes - each byte has to be one of the 256 combinations of bits.

What exactly do you mean when the soundcard returns `no any signal`?  Isn't that equivalent to zero voltage (i.e. use the integer value `0` in the file)?  Or are you using null as a placeholder to represent "unknown"?

You might still not be expressing your question fully - it sounds like you've decided that you need to put nulls in a file, and it doesn't seem like you justify this.  What are you *actually* trying to achieve (not "put nulls in a WAV") - and would this work with zeros?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "null signal". If you mean that you want no output just send 0 (If you are using signed values). If you are using unsigned values (which is not supported by Java), send 128 for 8-bit samples and 32768 for 16-bit samples.

So just say

```
data[]= {10,12,13,14,0,0,0,12,11,10};
```

followed by something like

```
yourSoundCardObject.write(data); //The method write is hypothetical
```

What is your sample rate?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried zeros, but it does not work for my case.